# Unable to determine successfull receiving of file

Tags: java, network-programming, nio, serversocket

I'm trying to send a file from server to client in java using **ServerSocketChannel** in the server class and **SocketChannel** in the client class. Both class objects are in blocking mode.

The file is been sent very well but am unable to programmatically determine that the file has reached! i have to go to the folder where the sent file is been saved in the client class to check it size and compare it size with the original file from the server class. this is because `System.out.println("received: "+filename);` statement is never executed in my client class. however the `System.out.println("file data sent");` in server class is executed.

**Server class code**

```
ServerSocketChannel ssc=ServerSocketChannel.open();
ssc.bind(new InetSocketAddress(5002));

SocketChannel clientchannel=ssc.accept();

FileChannel sbc=FileChannel.open(f.toPath());
                 ByteBuffer buff=ByteBuffer.allocate(10000000);
                 int size=(int)sbc.size();
                 int read=1000000;
                 System.out.println("file size: "+size);

                 int bytesread=sbc.read(buff);

                 while(bytesread != -1){

                buff.flip();
               clientchannel.write(buff);
                buff.clear();
                System.out.println("current position: "+sbc.position());
                bytesread=sbc.read(buff);
                 }
  System.out.println("file data sent");
```

**Client class code**

```
clientChannel=SocketChannel.open(address);
     ByteBuffer bb=ByteBuffer.allocate(10000000);
     int bytesRead=clientChannel.read(bb);

FileOutputStream bout =new FileOutputStream(file);
FileChannel sbc=bout.getChannel();

     while(bytesRead !=-1){
   System.out.println(" bytes read :"+bytesRead);
       bb.flip();
       sbc.write(bb);
       bb.clear();
      bytesRead=clientChannel.read(bb);
     }
     System.out.println("received: "+filename);
```

**Question**

what am i missing in my code that makes the last statement `System.out.println("received: "+filename);` not to be executed. its like my client program is put in a deadlock after all bytes have been received!

Answer (score 0):

You can close the channel in the server class after sending the file so that any further reads on the channel will return `-1`, the end-of-stream indication..

```
ServerSocketChannel ssc=ServerSocketChannel.open();
ssc.bind(new InetSocketAddress(5002));

SocketChannel clientchannel;
try{
clientchannel=ssc.accept();
FileChannel sbc=FileChannel.open(f.toPath());
             ByteBuffer buff=ByteBuffer.allocate(10000000);
             int size=(int)sbc.size();
             int read=1000000;
             System.out.println("file size: "+size);

             int bytesread=sbc.read(buff);

             while(bytesread != -1){

            buff.flip();
           clientchannel.write(buff);
            buff.clear();
            System.out.println("current position: "+sbc.position());
            bytesread=sbc.read(buff);
             }
System.out.println("file data sent");

}catch(IOException ioe){
ioe.printStackTrace();
}finally{
 if(clientchannel !=null){
        try {
            clientchannel.close();

        } catch (IOException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
        }
}
```